# Running multiple objects each on their own thread appears to run the same object multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, winapi, object

I'm trying to create 12 new instances of a class and run each of them it's a own thread, but they seam to share the same data.
all 12 instances are on the same X and Y position, but they each should move on a random direction.
as you can see in the code, i tried various apraoches and i can't find out why.

what am i doing wrong here?

p.s. yes ... i know there are still some unused variables.
p.s.s i have looked at many places and also here before i posted the question

enemy.cpp

```
#include "enemy.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>



FILE* pEnemyFile = fopen ("enemylog.txt","w");

Enemy::Enemy(const MouseServer& mServer, int& lastMousePosX, int& lastMousePosY, int& winSizeX, int& winSizeY )
    :mouseServer(mServer),
    lastMouseX( ( lastMousePosX ) ? lastMousePosX : 0 ), // evaluate if we get the reference
    lastMouseY( ( lastMousePosY ) ? lastMousePosY : 0 ),
    myPositionX(0),
    myPositionY(0),
    winSizeX(winSizeX),
    winSizeY(winSizeY),
    x(0),
    y(0)
{
    // original source:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx
    // Allocate memory for thread data.
    EDATA threadEnemyData = (EDATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,sizeof(enemyData));


    // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14746/Multithreading-Tutorial
    // http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/win32/article.php/c9823/Win32-Thread-Synchronization-Part-I-Overview.htm

    // usefull information
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3x8b09y(v=vs.100).aspx

     if( threadEnemyData == NULL )
     {
         //If the array allocation fails, the system is out of memory
         //so there is no point in trying to print an error message.
         //Just terminate execution.
         ExitProcess(2);
     }


    threadEnemyData->X = 0;
    threadEnemyData->Y = 0;

    this->hThread = CreateThread( 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        this->MyThreadFunction,
        this,
        /*threadEnemyData,*/
        0,
        &this->dwThreadID
    );


        // Check the return value for success.
        // If CreateThread fails, terminate execution. 
        // This will automatically clean up threads and memory. 

        if (this->hThread== NULL) 
        {
           ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
           ExitProcess(3);
        }
        //End of main thread creation loop.
}

Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
    WaitForSingleObject(this->hThread,INFINITE);

    // Close all thread handles and free memory allocations.
    this->hDefaultProcessHeap = GetProcessHeap();
    if (this->hDefaultProcessHeap == NULL) {
    }


    CloseHandle(this->hThread);
    //if(threadEnemyData != NULL)
    //{
    //  HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, threadEnemyData);
    //  hThread = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
    //}

    // close debug file
    fclose (pEnemyFile);
}

void Enemy::Draw(D3DGraphics& gfx)
{
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 0,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 1,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 2,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 3,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 4,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 5,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 6,this->y,255,255,255);
    gfx.PutPixel(this->x + 7,this->y,255,255,255);
}

// read
// http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1068278
DWORD WINAPI Enemy::MyThreadFunction( void* param ) 
{ 
    Enemy* self = (Enemy*) param;
    ////self->  // <-- "this"
    return self->NewThread();
}

  /* initialize random seed: */


// the itelligence loop of your enemy/object
DWORD Enemy::NewThread()
{
    do
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        /* generate random number: */
        //self->x += rand() % 4;
        //self->y += rand() % 4;
        this->x += rand() % 4;
        this->y += rand() % 4;


        // debug stuff
        char buffer[ 64 ];
        sprintf_s(buffer, "enemy:   x:   %d Y: %d id: %d\n", (char)this->x,  (char)this->y, (char)this->dwThreadID);
                fputs (buffer,pEnemyFile);

        // allow processor time to other threads
        Sleep(100);
    }while(true);  // endles loop
}

void Enemy::ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code.
    this->dw = GetLastError(); 
    // todo
}
```

enemy.h

```
#pragma once

#include "timer.h"
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Mouse.h"

/////// thread stuf
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    Enemy(const MouseServer& mServer, int& lastMousePos, int& lastMousePosY, int& winSizeX, int& winSizeY);
    ~Enemy();

    static DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam );
    DWORD Enemy::NewThread();
    void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

    void lookingForFood();
    void Draw(D3DGraphics& gfx);
    int Enemy::correctX(int xParam);
    int Enemy::correctY(int yParam);

private:
    int myPositionX;
    int myPositionY;
    int lastMouseX; 
    int lastMouseY;
    int winSizeX;
    int winSizeY;
    //int moveToX;  // todo
    //int moveToY;

    int x;
    int y;


    // threading stuff
    typedef struct ENEMYDATA // don't forget "typedef "
    {
        int X;
        int Y;  // test
    } enemyData, *EDATA;

    // Cast the parameter to the correct data type.
    // The pointer is known to be valid because 
    // it was checked for NULL before the thread was created.
    static Enemy* self;
    HANDLE  hThread;
    DWORD   dwThreadID;
    HANDLE hDefaultProcessHeap;
    DWORD dw; // error message

    EDATA* threadEnemyData;

    MouseClient mouseServer;
    //D3DGraphics& grafix;
    Timer timer;
};
```

Comment: Your `CreateThread` call passes the `this` pointer even though the constructor has not yet returned. If the thread dereferences that pointer before the constructor returns, which it clearly can, the thread would be accessing an object that wasn't fully constructed yet. Generally speaking, you should not create object-servicing threads in a constructor.

Comment: Should, i create another function and trigger it from the constructor or have the Game class on top of the Enemy class trigger that funtion?

thank you for your reply

Comment: I would suggest having some kind of `start` function that you call after the constructor returns.

Comment: one more question ...  constructor returns ... how to test this?

thank you

Comment: solved!
i added a startup function and test on ...
if(this != NULL){...this->hThread = CreateThread( 
  NULL, 
  0, 
  this->MyThreadFunction,
  this,
  0,
  &this->dwThreadID
 );
'''
}
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's commented out in your thread proc, but looks like you were on the right track:

srand ( time(NULL) );

It didn't work for you because all the threads start so fast that they end up with time(NULL) returning the same value for each thread. This means they're all using the same random sequence. Try seeding rand with the thread ID (or some other source that's unique per thread) and you should see unique pseudorandom number sequences.

Comment: you where faster, before i editted my post.
i saw "srand ( time(NULL) );" was commented out and corrected it

but that's not the error.

Comment: omg, sorry

but you're right
srand ( (unsigned int)this->dwThreadID ); 

thank you!

anything else that can be aproved .. regarding thread safety?

did the job